# How to get the last item from a Laravel database query array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Say I am querying the user table like this in Laravel:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/users', function()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
}
```

**users.blade.php**

```
<ul>
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->id }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

But I wanted the following with the last users id from the original query in the row below then how could I get that information?

**users.blade.php**

```
<ul>
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->id }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>

<div id="last-user" data-user-id="{{ $users->lastUserId }}"></div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use `last` to get the last item:

```
$last = $users->last();
```

Comment: So `$users->last()->id` ?